# ASP.Net Gridview within Listview - how to access listview previous row data

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview

I've checked for hours on google but cannot find solution to my specific problem.

I'm new to ASP.NET & c# - I have a listview that contains rows of data (meeting dates), within each of these is a gridview showing any associated files to download. All works fine. Now I want to add another row with option to upload a file to that meeting. Upload works fine but I need to access the parent listview rows CRMID field (to pass through to stored proc to update database). I have tried so much but can't seem to access it.

Any help would be really appreciated thanks. I attach code but it's prob best shown with a screen shot (I'm new to this site so cant upload one but one can be viewed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYf2o.jpg). When they click the upload button I want to access that CRMID from the previous row.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" DataKeyNames="CRMID">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th width="15px"> <%--"15px">--%>
                    </th>
                    <th width="10%">
                        CRMID
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Period
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Planned Date
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Actual Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        CRMNotes
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="Div1" class="SUBDIV" runat="server">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15px">
                            <div class="btncolexp collapse">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%">
                            <%#Eval("CRMID") %>
                        </td>
                        <td width="15%">
                            <%#Eval("PeriodDescr") %>
                        </td>
                        <td width="15%">
                            <%#Eval("CRMType") %>
                        </td>
                        <td width="15%">
                            <%#Eval("CRMPlannedDate", "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")%>
                        </td>
                        <td width="15%">
                            <%#Eval("CRMActualDate", "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("CRMNotes")%> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>                      
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8" style="border-bottom-style:none">
                            <div style="margin: 20px">
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="MasterListView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
                                            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                                             >
                                    <Columns>                                            
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="ContractReviewMeetingFileName" ItemStyle-Width="80%"/>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-Width="10%" >
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" 
                                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractReviewMeetingFileFullPath") %>' CommandName="cmdDownload">Download
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Upload Date" DataField="ContractReviewMeetingFileUploadDate" 
                                        DataFormatString="{0:d}" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
                                        <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="ContractReviewMeetingFileDescr" />--%>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8">                                
                            <div style="margin: 10px 20px 20px 80px; text-align:center">                                    
                                Upload File: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server"/>
                                <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" /><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
                            </div>                                
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And code behind (relevant function):

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            //FileUpload FileUploader = (FileUpload)ListView1.FindControl("FileUploader");
            var btn = (Button)sender;
            var item = (ListViewItem)btn.NamingContainer;     

            var FileUploader = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("FileUploader");
            var StatusLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("StatusLabel");
            // I've tried various forms of below with no joy..
            //var itemParent = (ListViewItem)item.NamingContainer;
            //var CRMID = itemParent.FindControl("CRMID");

            string DefaultFileName = @"\\BCVSTORE03\PublicHealthStore$\CMS\Testing\";

            if (FileUploader.HasFile)
                try
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
                    FileUploader.SaveAs(DefaultFileName + filename);//Server.MapPath(DefaultFileName) + filename);
                    //FileUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(DefaultFileName) +
                    //     FileUploader.FileName);
                         StatusLabel.Text = "File name: " +
                         FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                         FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                         "Content type: " +
                         FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentType + "<br><b>Uploaded Successfully";

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think you question shouldn't be an answer, it should be a comment really. Anyway, yes, i believe the right way is to use RowCommand for upload as well. You still should be able to get all infromation by `FindControl`, since RowCommand knows on which row it is triggered. But you also should be able to get row index, and use that to get the corresponding data key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FindControl call fails because there is no control to find. `<%# %>` does not output the control, just the string literal.

As a quick fix here is the suggestion. Have a hidden field nearby the upload control, that will provide you with the id:

```
Upload File: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="CRMIDHiddenField" Value='<%# Eval("CRMID") %>' />
```

And in the code behind use it:

```
var FileUploader = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("FileUploader");
var StatusLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("StatusLabel");
var CRMID = ((HiddenField)itemParent.FindControl("CRMIDHiddenField")).Value;
```

Other ways to fix that would be:

1. Use some control where you currently just output the CMDIR
2. [Proper way, in my opinion, but needs a lot of work] Refactor code to use list view commands instead of just individual controls events, and then use data keys.